# When to use Übernachten and when to use Übernachtung?

Tags: noun

I thought both of them mean the same – to stay overnight. Which to use in which case?

1. das Übernachten
2. die Übernachtung

Comment: What's your mother-tongue? Perhaps this is a feature which occur in your language as well. It's like in English: to read => the reading - to write => the writing. You have a verb and make it a noun. Hence; verb: übernachten - Noun: das Übernachten.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Übernachtung** is usually the noun you are looking for, and way more common. It often refers to the accommodation where you stay overnight as well (**Übernachtung in einem Hotel**):

> Wir brauchen ein Hotel für die nächste Übernachtung.

You will just get **das Übernachten** when reformulating sentences with the verb **übernachten**:

> Es ist verboten, hier zu übernachten. => Übernachten verboten!
>
> Es hat mir gefallen, bei dir zu übernachten. => Das Übernachten bei dir war schön.
>
> Als wir übernachtet haben, passierte etwas. => Beim Übernachten passierte etwas.

This is a style of writing German which you can avoid by using the verb.